# How to call a jQuery function like in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have this jQuery function:

```
$('.scrollToLoginBox').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#LoginBox").offset().top-5}, 'slow');                
});
```

I don't want it as a class, I'd like to be able to call it like this: `onClick="scrollTo(id);"`

So, how can I put the function in JavaScript format:

```
function scrollTo(id){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#'+id+'").offset().top-5}, 'slow');
}
```

EDITED by publisher:

I appreciate all your answers, but I'm not trying to get the id. On the other hand, I'm trying to build the same  function I published above. So, that on a click I will send the id (which I have Example Login or LoginBox), so that the function will scroll slowly to the anchor (id=Login or LoginBox).

Now I have to call it like this: `class="scrollToLoginBox"`, instead I'd like to call it `onClick="scrollTo('LoginBox');`.

I have 20 identical functions like the above, one for each id. Another example of what I have and I don't want is: `class="scrollToSettings"`, instead I'd like to call it `onClick="scrollTo('LoginBox');` or `onClick="scrollTo('Settings');`

```
            $('.scrollToSettings').click(function(e){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$("#settings").offset().top-5}, 'slow');         
        return false;       
    });
    
    $('.scrollToFaqs').click(function(e){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$("#formCode").offset().top-5}, 'slow');         
        return false;       
    });
```

I would like only one function that takes the id. I just don't know how to pass the id to this jQuery function ;o)

Comment: Why do you want to call it with `onclick`? Just make that event handler more generic.

Comment: ...Why? Why do you hate us so much?

Comment: I don't hate you ;o) I appreciate all the answers, but I'm not trying to get the id. On the other hand, I'm trying to build a function.

Comment: If your issue has been solved, please accept the answer that helped you solve the issue. If none of the answers helped, please provide your own answer to assist other users who may have the same problem and accept that one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to pass id to item being clicked, then you need to use `this.id`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/3YM7S/)**

```
onClick="scrollTo(this.id);"
```

If you want to pass id of `some other control` then you simple pass the id as string.

```
onClick="scrollTo('idOfHTMLElement');"
```

***Edit*** based on comments, for passing values from html elements to javascript function.

> Data attributes are used for hold custom attributes and could be
>   accessed in jQuery function use [data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) function.

**Html**

```
<div class="scrollToCal" data-idtopass="Anchor">click me to go to Anchor</div>​
```

**Javascript**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.scrollToCal').click(function() {

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#' + $(this).data('idtopass')).offset().top - 5
        }, 'slow');
        return false;
    });

});​
```

Comment: Thanks Adil, I want this but for the jQuery function I published. I already have the id. In my example, it would be: scrollTo('Login'); So, how do I modify my funcion to accept this way of calling it?

Comment: Could you make a fiddle? as I could not get what you want.

Comment: Hi Adil, I used Palash code, and started eliminating the id part. I noticed, not even the Alert works. I'm in noConflict mode. [this in my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sebababi/pGxP8/)

Comment: [and HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/sebababi/yY2DG/) is a working version with class. I have many Anchors, so here I don't know how to pass the Anchor id. Instead, I have a class for each of them, which is not good.

Comment: You can use data to pass values on click, check it here, http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/yY2DG/3/

Comment: SOLVED: Excellent Adil, Thanks a lot, this was the BEST SOLUTION

Comment: @Adil - is it worth updating your original answer with your latest solution? I cringe a little bit to think that an answer using `onclick` attributes could be marked as an accepted answer - obviously your latest JSFiddle avoids this.